# How do I change the state value of an interface property in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, state

I have an interface IRegister defined as such:

```
export default interface IRegister {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  dob: Date;
}
```

And a *register* object in state as such:

```
 const [register, setRegister] = useState<IRegister>({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    dob: new Date(),
    name: "",
    phone: "",
  });
```

The problem is that I'm unable to change the value of any of object *register*'s attributes. My current attempt is as follows (form using React Bootstrap) however it does not work:

```
 <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={register.email}
              onChange = {(e) => {setRegister(register.email)}}
              placeholder="Enter email"
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
```

How would I go about changing the value of an interface property using form input?

Comment: Firstly, always be more specific than "doesn't work". Does it give an incorrect result? Does it crash with an error message? Does your computer explode? Secondly, `setRegister` sets the *entire* register object, so you'll need to give an object with the rest of the properties spread in, plus you're setting the register equal to one of its own values, when you should set it to the value they type. Something like `onChange = {(e) => {setRegister({ ...register, email: e.target.value )}}` should work

Comment: Or you can try set state with callback argument: (e) => setRegister(prevState=>({...prevState, email: e.target.value}))

Comment: @captain-yossarian with react <17 you'll run into problems when using the event object in an async callback. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: @Yoshi , I'm sorry, but I don't unserstand what problem are You talking about. Could You please be more precise?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-sunset-kepg6?file=/src/App.js and try to enter something into the input. And this for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sorry I forgot to save the sandbox so that link wasn't very helpful, but it should work now.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks You very much! I'm not familiar with React hooks, but now I know more about  handling events.  I still use state only in class components. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Jayce444 Yes, that worked, thanks! Sorry for not adding more error information, posted the question from mobile while out so was not in a position to check the details.